# apply react setInterval, clearInterval useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, momentjs

I am trying to give a timer every 1 second in JSX using moment .

```
const onlive = useOnlive(); // react-query Custom Hook
console.log(onlive); 

{
    "event": {
        "id": 933,
        "startDate": "2023-01-17T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "nextEvent": {
        "id": 930,
        "startDate": "2023-01-18T13:20:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

I tried to create a timer by calculating nextEvent - currentTime and using the setInteval and clearInterval functions in useEffect to calculate the remaining time,
Timer doesn't work.

Why doesn't the timer (setInteval, clearInterval) fire every second?
Does the timer work when the useOnlive Custom API Hook is called every second?

```
const nextStartTime = moment(onlive.data?.nextEvent?.startDate); // 2023-01-18 
const nowTime = moment(); // current time 

  useEffect(() => {
      const nextStartTimeId = setInterval(() => {
        setHour(nextStartTime.diff(nowTime, 'hours', false) % 24);
        setMinute(nextStartTime.diff(nowTime, 'minutes', false) % 60);
        setSecond(nextStartTime.diff(nowTime, 'seconds', false) % 60);
      }, 100);
      return () => clearInterval(nextStartTimeId);
  }, [setHour, setMinute, setSecond, nextStartTime, nowTime]);

return (
               <span>
                   The session starts {hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour}:
                   {minute < 10 ? "0" + minute : minute}:
                   {second < 10 ? "0" + second : second} later.
               </span>
)
```

How can I make the timer work?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the interval to `100` **ms** instead of `1000` **ms**

```js
const nextStartTimeId = setInterval(() => {
  setHour(nextStartTime.diff(nowTime, "hours", false) % 24);
  setMinute(nextStartTime.diff(nowTime, "minutes", false) % 60);
  setSecond(nextStartTime.diff(nowTime, "seconds", false) % 60);
}, 1000);
```